# MYSQL database how to check if database is active and on which port (Linux)?

Tags: mysql, linux

I got the server and on it is some mysql database TEST.
I tried connected on it with my root account by using DBVisualizer but I keep getting could not connect check host name and port.

I tried with root account and also with TEST user account.
Their passwords are OK.

with command

```
mysql> show databases;
```

I found my TEST database.
I do not know any other parameters how to connect to database?
I suppose either root or test can connect to it.
How to check on which port is the database or does it have to be active?

I tried with netstat and this is my response? what  does it mean?

```
netstat -an | grep -i mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8596     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your mysql connection is only listening by unix sockets and now by the actual TCP.

To solve that, go to your configuration file, usually on **/etc/mysql/** folder with the name **my.cnf** on Ubuntu(if you are using some other system should be similar).

In the configuration file you should have a section called **[client]**.

make your server to listen on 127.0.0.1:3306 by:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
#socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
host = 127.0.0.1
```

And than restart the server.

Now you should have access to the mysql shell by doing on your command line.

```
mysql -U TEST -h 127.0.0.1 -p db_name
```

Or you can use any other client you want.

Comment: hi, thanks for reply i am having some progress. now I can make new connection in DBVisualizer but I still can not connect. mysql is on server 192.168.0.1 and my ip adress is 192.168.0.55 so now when i try telnet I am getting Host 192.168.0.55 is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL server

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with bind address field http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/27/allow-remote-connections-to-your-mysql-server/ it says it should be commented and granted privileges on my ip adress 192.168.0.55 but that is stupid because every day on work I will have another IP adress

Comment: Hi, now all you have to do its to bind your address(IP). Go to the same file and and look for the bind-address option. It should be 0.0.0.0 I think.

Comment: do I have to change and bind address and host that you added?? but tomorrow I will have another IP address on my work does it sound silly to change every day address in that file?

Comment: Sorry I understood you to put my local adress. OK so you suggest to change from bindadress 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 am I right?

Comment: I still can not connect and do telnet

Comment: hey, I couldn't answer yesterday. 
check [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) documentation.

If after this you still can't connect, you might have some permission problem where your username is not allowed to connect from an external IP address. Have a look on [Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connection-access.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I succeeded connected but not on this way. I commented bind address I did not add host. After that I did GRANT ACCESS ON *.* ROOT@MYIPADRESS IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD. Only problem is that my current ip address is 192.168.0.141 but we are using DHCP so tomorrow by address will be changed so every time I must do command GRANT ACCESS with different IP address to connect to mysql server? Is there any solution for this? Thanks, BR